# Conditionally print a TITLE in SAS?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am making a macro and want to display different titles for different variables that go through my macro.

I have been trying something like below:

```
%MYMACRO (VARIABLE);
%IF &VARIABLE='MYVARIABLE' %THEN TITLE1 'TITLE A';
    %ELSE TITLE1 'TITLE B';
/* MY MACRO STUFF */
%MEND MYMACRO;
```

This doesn't work.  I am most likely not going about this in the proper manner either.  I am wondering if there is an easy way to do this or if I need to do it manually each time I want to change my titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your macro variable doesn't resolve to a quoted string, you will need to fix your conditional.  For example like this:

```
%IF "&VARIABLE"="MYVARIABLE" %THEN TITLE1 'TITLE A';
```

This should be true when you run this:

```
%mymacro(MYVARIABLE);
```

Or the conditional in our example should resolve to true if you run this:

```
%mymacro('MYVARIABLE');
```